# After saving/exporting a plot in matlab, any subsequent plot fails

Tags: matlab, plot

I run `plot(...)` followed by `xlabel(...)` and a couple of other functions to add a title and a y label  - the plot is produced fine and I can repeat this as often as I want.

But if I do as above and then use the options on the File dropdown at the top of the figure's window to Save/Export the figure (as .png), the next time I run `plot(...)` I get an empty figure and a warning saying

"Warning: An error occurred while drawing the scene"

Any idea why this is? So far the only way around it I have is to close and reopen matlab...

**EDIT:**

The minimal code I run to produce this is

```
x = linspace(0, 10, 1000);
plot(x, x)
plot(x, x)
```

Between the first and second `plot(...)` I go to File->Save As and save it as .png on the menu on the figure window. The the next `plot(...)` command then creates an empty figure and prints

```
Warning: An error occurred while drawing the scene
```

Comment: Can you describe step-by-step what are you doing? Because it works for me.

Comment: I've added the minimal code I used to create the error, I am using the trial version of Matlab R2014b (I had used another copy of this trial before with no issues)

Comment: I am using an older one (R2011a) and can't reproduce the error. So, I guess some version specific bug.

Comment: Sounds like a bug, yes. What operating system do you use? Can you start Matlab from a terminal/command window? What does it say there?